# fill groups with values based on group values (update with group bys) - SQL - postgre

Tags: mysql, postgresql, group-by

I have the situation in which I produce some output, and based on the gorup of belonging, it gets and index (common for the group). then I the production goes on and I insert some new values that belong to the very same group. I want to assign to these new records the same "marker" that the group already had. I'd like to do it with `SQL` alone.
as detailed in the picture below, the groups are composed by a tuple (continent, zone, state) which I, in fact, group by. (table name: '`geo`')

[image]

How can I put the number 5 aside manchester and 6 aside Lyon?

Comment: How are you currently handling the case where a record gets inserted which is the first one for a given continent, zone, state, city combination?  How is the `group` value determined in this case?

Comment: you make a good point effectively. I used a python based solution (programmatic) since the batch was small. but the table will grow to be gigantic. I would be open also to rewrite all the group indexes completely as long as they are unique numbers group wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are OK with first inserting the data, and then running a second query to update the blank group numbers, then there is one option:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
SET group = t2.group
FROM
(
    SELECT continent, zone, state
           MAX(group) AS group
    FROM yourTable
    GROUP BY continent, zone, state
) t2
WHERE t1.continent = t2.continent AND
      t1.zone      = t2.zone      AND
      t1.state     = t2.state
```

The inner query in the `FROM` clause finds the maximum `group` value for each continent, zone, state combination.  There should only be two types of values for each `group` combination, namely a number and/or a `NULL`.  The `NULL` value would indicate that the record were newly inserted, but it would be ignored by the `MAX` function.

Comment: thanks mate. and yes I am fine with first inserting the data because that is exactly how my procedure is built in

Comment: @Asher11 Reload the page.  I think you only need to group by the continent, zone, and state.